# VSC throws invalid syntax error when running script after running selected line

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I just started using VSC for Python/Anaconda and to be honest its been given me headaches from day one, however it has a ton of great stuff so I am trying to stick with it. My most recent problem is that if I "Run Python file in terminal" everything works, then if I "Run Selection/line in Python terminal" everything still works, but then if I after that "Run Python file in terminal" again it produces a "File , line 1" Syntaxerror...

I am very much not sure exactly what is going on or how to fix it, tried looking for answers by to no avail.

The below is the code that I run, when I select I select all of it:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
test=1
print("qwe")
print("asd")
```

Comment: Can you share a snippet and what you are selecting ? Probably your selection set is wrong

Comment: Sure thing, I select the entire code

Comment: Do you have too many folders open in the same workspace.Looks like the settings is messed up for some reason. I had the same issue when using it in a window with multiple folders.But, when i created a fresh workspace and configured the virtual env it works as expected

Comment: Did you quit the REPL before you started to use "Run Python file in terminal" the second time? Both commands you are using are just sending text to your shell, so if you didn't quit the REPL then the extension is just pasting the execution command into the `>>>` prompt.

Answer (score 1):

When you `Run Selection/line in Python terminal`, it turns to REPL. Source code that runs in the terminal/REPL is cumulative until the current instance of the terminal is closed. If you want to `Run Python file in terminal` again, you must exit REPL by input exit()

[image]

Comment: For some reason, even code that should work cumulatively fails if you don't exit the REPL. For example, if your code is just `print("Hello World")`, executing "Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal" followed by "Run Python File in Terminal" still results in a syntax error.